# QueryOver to select an entity

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have a question. I have this query:

```
 var query = QueryOver.Of<Item>()
                .JoinQueryOver<ItemRelation>(p => p.ItemRelation)
                .Where(r => r.Item1.Id == itemId)
```

How can I return only Item entity but not Item Relation?

Thanks

Comment: Luka: I google-translated your entity names. Having them in English usually reduces the "mental-noise" one has to deal with and will help you get answers in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query actually should only return Predmet ... The RelacijaPredmeta is a property of it. If you don't want to load it, use lazy loading, or select the properties of Predmet individually.